# NavigationBar sub-menu is not clickable

Tags: html, css, reactjs, vite, css-modules

My StackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-39yyir?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHeader%2FNavigationBar.jsx

The problem.

Sub-menu is not clickable. As soon as you move the mouse, the menu collapses.

This is with Vite/React project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-gytcso?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHeader%2FNavigationBar.jsx) and commented out some conflicting logic.

Comment: What was conflicting?